# Questions about ellipse

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Given the center of an ellipse and three of its points, is this ellipse completely determined?

What is the easiest way to show that five points of an ellipse are enough to determine the ellipse?

Comment: Are we assuming the major and minor axes are parallel to the $x$-axis and $y$-axis respectively?

Comment: One way to show that 5 points is enough would be that an ellipse is defined by $ax^2+by^2+cx+dy+e=0$ and that is 5 unknowns.  So you would need 5 linear equations to solve it.

Comment: If no pair of the points on the ellipse are already antipodal, then we can use each point and the center point to create an antipodal point for each of the original three, giving us six points on the ellipse. By what @turkeyhundt says, this will determine the ellipse. Now the case where two of the points are antipodal ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping that I am not wrong : the general equation of the ellipse write $$Ay^2+B x y+C x^2+D y + E x+ F=0$$ Dividing by $A$, it then reduces to $$y^2+\alpha xy+\beta x^2+\gamma y +\delta x+\epsilon=0$$ Since we know the center $(x_0,y_0)$, make a change of variable $x=x_0+X$, $y=y_0+Y$ (in order to eliminate the $x$ and $y$ terms) and it becomes $$Y^2+\alpha' XY+\beta'X^2+\gamma'=0$$ So, three equations are at least required, so three points if you know the center.

Comment: *three equations are at least required* - True. Three *independent* equations. But, given the fact that the ellipse is symmetrical with respect to both of its axes, this independence is not guaranteed. In fact, we might just as well have four equations, corresponding to four homologue points, but they only count as one independent equation, as it has already been pointed out in the other answer, as well as the comment section.

Comment: @Lucian. For sure ! You are perfectly correct : they must be independent. Thanks for pointing it. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first part is: NO. Let us consider 4 edges of a square. There are infinitely many ellipses going through these 4 points.

Comment: But he designated one point as the center of the ellipse. Since we have three points and the center, I don't quite see how your example serves as a counter-example.

Comment: @mapierce271 The center of a square is the center of an an ellipse. How many of them exist?